# UIViewcontroller giving wrong orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview

I have a `UIViewController` having a `UICollectionView` (in portrait mode).

I am presenting a second `UIViewController` top of `firstviewcontroller`(now in Portrait mode). Then I am rotating `secondviewcontroller`(now in landscape mode).

Then I am dismissing `secondviewcontroller` (now in landscape mode).

Now in the first `UIViewController`, the `UICollectionView` items are arranging according to portrait mode. But it should be according to landscape mode. Instead of landscape mode it is taking portrait mode and vice vera.

Comment: Code? or at least an image of your problem?

Comment: Sounds to be like you have a layout issue of the child views of the first VC and not the VC it self. As above, code or an image of the issue would help us help you a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your ViewController:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

[Check Apple source for more information](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621435-supportedinterfaceorientations)